# I have been using Node JS and NPM for several years with no issues. Suddenly I am receiving an error with any NPM command

Tags: node.js, npm

I am not sure at all what changed. There were a couple of app upgrades that I ran which might or might not have caused the issue. I believe this may be an issue with the path but I am really not sure. That is the reason I am posting here. Thanks for your help in advance.

This is what I receive when I attempt to run any NPM command:

```
C:\>node -v
v12.18.3

C:\>npm -v
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:329
      throw err;
      ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\dhash\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\write-file-atomic\index.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
    at tryPackage (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:321:19)
    at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:682:18)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:27)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:841:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\dhash\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\cache-file.js:5:25)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\dhash\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\write-file-atomic\\package.json',
  requestPath: 'write-file-atomic'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this problem
First: I uninstalled Node JS from my machine (I am not sure this was needed but I did it)

Second: I copied all of the directories from the (Node JS
install)\node_modules\npm\node_modules directory to the c:\Users(user
name)\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules directory

Now it appears that all the npm stuff works. When I run the two commands to get the current versions it returns the correct information.

D:>node -v

v12.18.3

D:>npm -v

6.14.7

I am not sure how things were confused but it appears that at some point in time over the  last couple of years that the AppData location had stopped being updated. When I did an update the path was set back to the AppData and that data was very old. By copying over the node_modules for the new install to the AppData location it appears at this point that everything was updated.

I hope this helps someone else in the future.